# Copy graphite dashboard to another graphite dashboard

Tags: copy, dashboard, graphite

I have a production graphite dashboard. I've saved some graphs under the tag `abc` so that you can access it using `http://prod-graphite.com/dashboard/abc`.

I've another dashboard for staging hosted on different server. Let's say the URL is `http://staging-graphite.com/dashboard/`.

I want to copy all the graphs of prod `/abc` to staging as I don't want to go through the trouble of creating 20 graphs again. I've tried the [Copy Dashboard](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dashboard.html#other-operations-on-the-graph) feature provided by graphite but it is not working. Nothing happens when I enter the prod URL. any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GET/POST http://your.graphite.host/dashboard/load/YOUR_DASHBOARD_NAME - gives you dump of specified dashboard. It returns json with `state` as root object, that holds dashboards' structure.

POST http://your.graphite.host/dashboard/save/NEW_DASHBOARD_NAME - lets you save data as new dashboard. Requires `state` parameter with dashboards' structure.

Oneliner, fetchs dump, prepares body, save:

```
curl -o- http://graphite.host/dashboard/load/DASH_NAME | \
python -c "import json,sys,urllib;o=json.load(sys.stdin);print('state=%s' % urllib.quote(json.dumps(o['state'])));" | \
curl -X POST http://graphite.host/dashboard/save/COPY_OF_DASH_NAME -d @-
```